# man xargs says standard input is delimited by blanks; but is it?

Tags: quoting, xargs

I'm puzzled by what actually defines an **arg** in `xargs`.
The man page seems to suggest that args are delimited by blanks (I assume that means whitespace).  However, the following script doesn't behave as I would expect. Here is an excerpt from man's DESCRIPTION section:

> xargs reads items  from the standard input, delimited by blanks (which
>   can be protected with double or single quotes or a  backslash)  or 
>   new‐lines, and  executes  the  command ...

It seems that perhaps xargs works in *blocks* of what the man-page calls *items*.  Does this mean a `null-delimited` item, or a `newline` delimited item?

Basically, I don't understand why, in the following script, `xargs` treats the input as a single arg, even though the spaces (in stdin) are *not protected*.  I expected `xargs` to treat stdin as 3 args, or at least reduce multiple spaces to a single space, but it does neither of these!

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 == "." ]] ;then  # act on a recursive call to self
    shift                 # scrap the 'recursive' arg
    printf '|%s|\n' "$@"  # print all 'xargs' args
    printf '|%s|\n' "$1"  # print only the first 'xargs' arg
    exit
fi
printf 'a    b    c\n' |xargs -I {} "$0" "." {}
```

---

Here is the output; showing only a single arg was passed to the script.

```
|a    b    c|
|a    b    c|
```

But I would have expected 3 separate args, like this:

```
|a|
|b|
|c|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read what the manual page says about option `-I`, which you are using:

#### -I replace-str

> Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.  **Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline character.**

Comment: OMG! That was easy! I was looking at the wrong things... thanks ;) ...

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't about “blocks” vs “items”, that's just shifting terminology. `xargs` takes input quoted with `'` or `"` and delimited by blanks, except when certain options are passed.

Some options change to line-by-line processing with no quoting: `-I`, `-L`, `-i` (GNU), `-l` (GNU). The option `-0` (where available) changes to null-delimited input with no quoting. The option `-d` (GNU) changes to a custom delimiter with no quoting.

Answer (score -1):

One of the reasons for making GNU Parallel was to make it more predictable than xargs. https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/history.html

If you get hit by the way xargs interprets arguments, consider using GNU Parallel instead.

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
```

Watch the intro videos for GNU Parallel to learn more:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Comment: Please only mention Parallel when you have a useful example, otherwise it seems like spam.  You have copy-pasted this into several answers today.